# Replace a single character in a string

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that automatically generated a response to a selection of an action in a text adventure game. My problem is that I have to replace every second '_' with ' '. However I have tried everything I have though of and whenever I google the question the only solution I get is to use .replace(). However .replace() replaces every instance of that character. Here is my code, could you please fix this for me and explain how you fixed it.

```
example_actions = ['[1] Search desk', '[2] Search Cupboard', '[3] Search yard'

def response(avaliable_actions):
    for i in avaliable_actions:
        print(i, end=' ')
        x = avaliable_actions.index(i)
        avaliable_actions[x] = avaliable_actions[x][4:]
    
    avaliable_actions = ' '.join(avaliable_actions)
    avaliable_actions = avaliable_actions.lower()

    avaliable_actions = avaliable_actions.replace(' ', '_')
    avaliable_actions = list(avaliable_actions)
    count = 0
    for i in avaliable_actions:
        if count == 2:
            count = 0
            index = avaliable_actions.index(i)
            avaliable_actions[index] = ' '
        elif i == '_':
            count += 1
            

    avaliable_actions = ' '.join(avaliable_actions)
            
    print('\n\n' + str(avaliable_actions)) #error checking
```

Comment: which is your expected result?

Comment: If your intention is to have the underscores within the action string and spaces between different actions, you could replace the spaces in the action strings before concatenating with spaces, so at this stage: `avaliable_actions[x][4:].replace(' ','_')`

Comment: (also aaargh, `avaliable` rather than `available`??)

Comment: @Nikappa_ expected result is 'search_house search_desk search_yard'

Comment: @Joffan it didn't work

Comment: @Rumblefish you would also need to remove the later `replace` operation and the subsequent `for` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
s = 'here_is_an_example_of_a_sentence'

tokens = s.split('_')
result = ' '.join('_'.join(tokens[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(tokens),2))
print(result)
```

The result:

```
here_is an_example of_a sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand you correct, that you wanna produce something like this?

`this_is_a_test` -> `this is_a test` or `this_is a_test`?

If so, adapt the following for your needs:

```py
s = "this_is_just_a_test"

def replace_every_nth_char(string, char, replace, n):
    parts = string.split(char)
    result = ""
    for i, part in enumerate(parts):
        result += part
        if i % n == 0:
            result += replace
        else:
            result += char
    return ''.join(result)

res = replace_every_nth_char(s, "_", " ", 2)
print(s, "->", res)
# "this_is_just_a_test" -> "this is_just a_test"
```